# CE1.9.2.4 - Prevent customer shipping address edit

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-address, customer-address, ce-1.9.2.4

As part of a B2B site, one of the business requirements is to prevent customers from editing their shipping address (customer accounts are created by an admin person).

What is the best (non-destructive) way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: customers can edit shipping address in their account section, you can hide the `edit` buttton.

Comment: Hiding the edit button won't prevent them from adding a new address during the checkout though

Comment: Look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222768/how-limit-magento-2-shipping-addresses-in-checkout