# How limit magento 2 shipping addresses in checkout

Tags: magento-2.1.7, shipping-address

I want to show one shipping address per login customer in checkout shipping sections. How can I do  it in magento 2.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the file in your local theme from

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\shipping-address\list.js

Modify the function ,

```
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initChildren: function () {

        if(addressList().length > 0){
            this.createRendererComponent(addressList()[0],this); /* It always set the first shipping address. Change the logic as per your requirement */
        }
        else{
            _.each(addressList(), this.createRendererComponent, this);
        }

        return this;
    },
```

To hide New Address button,

Copy the html template from

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html

To the local theme and comment the below code

```
        <if args="!isFormInline">
            <button type="button"
                    class="action action-show-popup"
                    click="showFormPopUp"
                    visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
                <span translate="'New Address'" />
            </button>
            <div id="opc-new-shipping-address"
                 visible="isFormPopUpVisible()"
                 render="shippingFormTemplate" />
        </if>
```

Comment: Updated the code to always get the first shipping address

Comment: it works but need to disable add new address button.

Comment: Updated the code to remove new address button.

Comment: @ saravanavelu thanks. are there any way to disable using backend, I have a doubt what can I do when client request to enable it again,

Comment: It is possible to control that from backend by default. need to customize based on your requirement.

Comment: can you add the backend path to do it. thanks

Comment: Sorry it is not possible to control from admin, typo error.

Comment: How the addresses is rendered? In which file it is setting? Any block file?